# How to Recursively Add Projects to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there an extension or add-in that will search the file system and add existing projects to a solution?  I had a macro in VS2K10 but it no longer works in 2012.  I'd even be happy to pay for it.  The previous macro worked like this...

- Create and open the Solution;
- Right-click the solution node... Folder Browser opens;
- Select folder to start search from;
- Macro scans file system and adds found projects to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.addfromtemplate(v=vs.120).aspx

It creates a solution, adds an existing project and save the sln to disk.

Adding the folder scan logic should be quite simple.

hope it helps.